# Zero Activity Example

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to Android development, As we read An application can have zero or more activities in android. Can anybody give me some example of zero activity application.

Answer (score 2):

A zero Activity application is no longer possible from Android 3.1 onwards as the user must launch any one of the activities in a app at least once before it can receive other events like Broadcasts.

Before Android 3.1, any app that can accomplish its task in a service could be a Zero Activity app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is no longer possible on Android OS 3.1 and above. 
    http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html